# How do I make new fields appear in the form based upon the selection of an option button in InfoPath 2010

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules, feature-dependency

I'm new to using InfoPath. I am looking to have new fields (both the label and control) appear in the form based upon a previous answer.

For example: Do you like to go to the movies? then I have two option buttons of Yes and No. 
If they select Yes I would like lines to open below that say: What is your favorite movie? with a text box control and Who is your favorite charater? with a text box control.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with sections and conditional formatting.

Add a section and inside the section add the fields that you want to show/hide.
Go to Section properties -> Display tab -> Conditional formatting and enter the condition.

In your case the condition will based on whether the user has selected Yes or No in the field that contains the answer for the question “Do you like to go to the movies?”.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Naim Murati's answer - be sure to select the NOT EQUALS in the condition, as the option is only to HIDE the section, rather than unhide. Took my pea brain a few minutes to figure that out, so I thought I'd share.